# how can i handle dojox.grid.cells.combobox on change events

Tags: javascript, dojo

I create a grid using dojo with a column structure like this :
{
 'name' : 'Type',
 'field' : 'type',
 'width' : '150px',
 type: dojox.grid.cells.ComboBox,
 editable : true,
 options: [ 'Numérique', 'Date', 'Chaîne de caractères', 'Boite à cocher' ,'Liste'], 
 styles : "text-align: center;"
}
Is there any way to handle the "onchange" events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest and best way to handle the onChange event is to do it like this:

```
 yourGridName.on('Change',function(evt){
      //do something when an onChange happend
    });
```

Have a look in the Eventhandler of dojo for further information:http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html#dojo-on

Regards, Miriam